# Is the optimization of a symmetric function a symmetric solution?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Under the assumption that $x^2+y^2=c^2$ I minimized the functions $P=x^{-1}+y^{-1}$ and $Q=x^{-2}+y^{-2}$ and for both the solution was $x^2=y^2=c^2/2$. I noticed that the condition equation and the function to be optimized were both symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

Let $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ be symmetric functions. If we have the condition that $F(x,y)=C$ and we solve the equation $\dfrac{d}{dx}G(x,y)=0$ will $x=y$ be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a counterexample:**

Suppose $F(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 = 1$, and we want to minimize the function $G(x,y)= x^2+y^2$. Both $F(x,y)$ and $G(x,y)$ are symmetric.

As $0\le x^2,y^2\le 1$, we have:
$$x^2(1- x^2)\ge0$$
$$y^2(1- y^2)\ge0$$
$$\implies x^2+y^2\ge x^4+y^4 = 1 \tag{1}$$

The equality of $(1)$ occurs if and only if $(x,y) = (\pm1,0)$ or $(0,\pm 1)$. The solution is not symmetric (in other words, $x\ne y$).

Comment: Do you also know how to solve the problem in general? If x and y are related such that $y=h(x)$ and you want to min/max $F(x,y)=F(x,h(x))$ how do you go about it?

Comment: @MumboJumbo if you know $y = h(x)$, here is the generic [solution](https://byjus.com/jee/maxima-and-minima-in-calculus/) : find the roots of $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{dF(x,h(x)}{dx} = 0$ (suppose the roots are $x_1, x_2,...$) and then check the sign of the second derivative $\frac{d^2F(x_i,h(x_i)}{dx^2}$ for $i=1,2,...$

Comment: So minumum occurs at the boundary for the variables $x^2,y^2$... Where does maximum occur?

Answer (score 1):

What is the minumum of the function $f(x,y)=xy$ under the constraint $x^2+y^2=1$?

The answer is $-\frac12$ and it is attained at the points $(\frac1{\sqrt2}, -\frac1{\sqrt2})$
and $(-\frac1{\sqrt2}, \frac1{\sqrt2})$ which are not symmetric but anti-symmetric, i.e. $y=-x$ for these points.